# Fnd a sequence to be convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Varablies  $X_1,\ldots ,X_n$ are independent and $\forall {i\in\{1,\ldots n\}}: X_i \sim \exp(1)$. Find numeric string $a_n$ such that sequence of random variables $$Y_n= \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\} - a_n$$ is convergent in distribution.

---

I have distribution $\exp(1)$ i.e.

$$F_X(t)=  \begin{cases} 1-e^{-t} &\text{if } t \ge 0\\
0 &\text{if }   t<0 \end{cases}
$$
and I have that the distribution of $\max\{X_1,\ldots X_n\}$ is equal to $\left(F_X (t)\right)^n$. I can't find sequence $a_n$ to be convergent in distribution.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly calculate the distribution $F_n$ of the random variable $Y_n$, where $$F_n(y)=P(Y_n\le y)$$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $y \in \mathbb R$. For $y>0$ you have that $$\begin{align*}F_n(y)&=P(\max\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}-a_n \le y)=\\[0.2cm]&=P(\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}\le y+a_n)=\left(F_X(y+a_n)\right)^n=\left(1-e^{-y-a_n}\right)^n\end{align*}$$ The RHS goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ if $y+a_n>0$ and $a_n$ bounded and diverges if $y+a_n<0$ and $a_n$ unbounded. Therefore an appropriate choice is to take $a_n \to \infty$ (quickly enough) as $n \to \infty$, for example $a_n:=n$. Then you have that $$F_n(y)=\left(1-e^{-y-n}\right)^n\longrightarrow 1 $$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $y>0$. Thus $$Y_n:=\max\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}-n \overset{d}\longrightarrow 0$$ as $n \to \infty$. With $0$ is denoted the degenerate random variable $Y\equiv 0$ with distribution function $$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0, & y<0\\[0.2cm] 1, & y\ge 0\end{cases}$$